# I don't know what I've got or if it's drinkable?

Tags: fermentation

for several months now I have been squeezing my ripened citrus and storing it in an air tight bottle in the fridge.  I drink or add it to something from time to time and continually add juice to it. On Saturday I went to drink some and it had a Kombucha like fizz when I tasted it. What is this and is it drinkable?  Have I created something good or is it filled with bad bacteria?  Help before I throw it out please.

Comment: If you think there is any chance at all that it has been contaminated with bad bacteria, then don't take any risks and pour it away.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you haven't gotten sick yet, so its safe enough to drink.

You're probably getting spontaneous fermentation from whatever was growing on the fruit. The low pH of citrus makes this safe in terms of bacterial growth, but yeasts and mold could be growing in it. And maybe some lactobacillus, which is a plus in my opinion. So maybe its safe, or maybe your urologist will tell you in a few years how much [ochratoxin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ochratoxin) that mold was making.

Next time you can throw some proper yeast in there to be sure its safe.

As far as what it is, it would fall under the umbrella of [pruno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pruno), although some Brits I know, who are not convicts, insist it is called turbo cider.

For further entertaining info I recommend [google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=fermented+orange+vomit)